# Keepalived - How to change master owner when node goes down?

Tags: high-availability, keepalived

Hello I would like to know if there any possibilities with keepalived to : change master owner when node goes down ?

In order to illustrate my question :

[standard behavior]
Keepalived cluster with node 1 **(master)** and node 2 **(slave)**.
When **(master)** is going down, **(slave)** is handly the traffic
When **(master)** is goind up and **(master)** is getting back the work to handlying the traffic

[attended behavior]
Keepalived cluster with node1 **(origin-master)** and node2 **(origin-slave)**.
When **(origin-master)** is going down, **(origin-slave)** is handlying the traffic and become **(new-master)**
When **(origin-master)** is goind up and **(new-slave)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was to use a Master > Slave state.
In order to work as I wanted in [attended behavior] I had to setup Backup > Backup state :

```
# Node1
vrrp_instance VI_TEST_1 {

  state BACKUP
  priority 150
  nopreempt

# Node2
vrrp_instance VI_TEST_1 {
  state BACKUP
  priority 100
  nopreempt
```

I hope it will help someone!